# Non-numerical type returned by curried function

Tags: scala, currying

New to Scala and functional programming in general. Have the following code snippet which means to calculate the sum over a closed interval of `Int`s. Have implemented both tail-recursive method (`sum1`) and non-tail-recursive method (`sum2`).

```
package test

import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Currying extends App{

  def sum1(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int, b:Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {
    require(a <=  b, "Received a=" + a + " and b=" + b)
    @tailrec
    def sum(a:Int, acc:Int) : Int = {
      if(a > b) acc
      else sum(a+1, acc + f(a))
    }
    sum
  }

  println("sum1(x=>x*x)(1, 4)=" + sum1(x=>x*x)(1, 4))
  println("sum1(x=>x*x*x)(1, 4)=" + sum1(x=>x*x*x)(1, 4))

  def sum2(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int, b:Int): Int => Int = {
    def sum(a:Int) : Int = {
      if(a > b) 0
      else f(a) + sum(a+1)
    }
    sum
  }

  println("sum2(x=>x*x)(1, 4)=" + sum2(x=>x*x)(1, 4))
  println("sum2(x=>x*x*x)(1, 4)=" + sum2(x=>x*x*x)(1, 4))

}
```

The print-outs, however, do *not* return actual `Int`s, but what appears to be a function itself:

```
sum(x=>x*x)(1, 4)=week2.Currying$$$Lambda$12/1468177767@3d24753a
sum(x=>x*x*x)(1, 4)=week2.Currying$$$Lambda$12/1468177767@67b64c45
sum2(x=>x*x)(1, 4)=week2.Currying$$$Lambda$15/1626877848@2f7a2457
sum2(x=>x*x*x)(1, 4)=week2.Currying$$$Lambda$15/1626877848@6108b2d7

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Clearly I'm doing something dumb in the currying, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Your functions literally return functions, the second parameter list is followed by `: Int => Int`, so even after applying the two parameter lists, you still need to apply one argument to get an int

Comment: the ending part is just sum but not sum(a,b), isn't it supposed to return the function obj itself, since you are not calling it?

Comment: Why would they return `Int`s? You are returning functions. `sum1` returns an `(Int, Int) => Int`, `sum2` returns an `Int => Int`.

Comment: In both cases, the `a` parameter to `def sum()` shadows the `a` parameter received by the surrounding method. Thus the `a` parameter passed to `sum1()` and `sum2()` goes unreferenced and unused.

Comment: You are all correct. I got lost in a labyrinth of notation and lost the big picture of the function signature. All good.